# ¿Cómo desactivar la validación de los NameSpace de la función simplexml_load_string en PHP5?

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente string que le paso a la función simplexml_load_string

```
<DIN  xmlns:ns36="http://www.aduana.cl/xml/esquemas/EnvioDin" xmlns:ns33="http://www.aduana.cl/xml/esquemas/ERRORES"  xmlns:ns3="http://www.aduana.cl/xml/esquemas/CABEZA">
    <ns36:CABEZA>
        <ns3:NUMIDENTIF>123123</ns3:NUMIDENTIF>
        <ns3:RESPUESTA>
            <ns9:FECHACEPTACION></ns9:FECHACEPTACION>
            <ns9:NUMEROENCRIPTADO></ns9:NUMEROENCRIPTADO>
            <ns9:ESTADO>formato incorrecto, error en la firma del documento. java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException:  algorithm and DOM mechanism not available</ns9:ESTADO>
            <ns9:TIPOSELECCION></ns9:TIPOSELECCION>
        </ns3:RESPUESTA>
    </ns36:CABEZA>
    <ns36:ERRORES>
        <ns33:ERROR>
            <ns34:CODIGO>999</ns34:CODIGO>
            <ns34:GLOSA>formato de din incorrecto</ns34:GLOSA>
        </ns33:ERROR>
    </ns36:ERRORES>
</DIN>
```

la función me retorna false no me carga el XML y además no me retorna ningún error.

Pero cuando le paso el mismo XML sin el ns36 de las etiquetas de segundo nivel si me lo carga sin problemas

```
<DIN  xmlns:ns36="http://www.aduana.cl/xml/esquemas/EnvioDin" xmlns:ns33="http://www.aduana.cl/xml/esquemas/ERRORES"  xmlns:ns3="http://www.aduana.cl/xml/esquemas/CABEZA">
    <CABEZA>
        <ns3:NUMIDENTIF>123123</ns3:NUMIDENTIF>
        <ns3:RESPUESTA>
            <ns9:FECHACEPTACION></ns9:FECHACEPTACION>
            <ns9:NUMEROENCRIPTADO></ns9:NUMEROENCRIPTADO>
            <ns9:ESTADO>formato incorrecto, error en la firma del documento. java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException:  algorithm and DOM mechanism not available</ns9:ESTADO>
            <ns9:TIPOSELECCION></ns9:TIPOSELECCION>
        </ns3:RESPUESTA>
    </CABEZA>
    <ERRORES>
        <ns33:ERROR>
            <ns34:CODIGO>999</ns34:CODIGO>
            <ns34:GLOSA>formato de din incorrecto</ns34:GLOSA>
        </ns33:ERROR>
    </ERRORES>
</DIN>
```

como hago para que me cargue el primer XML ?